# Help with math steps, chain rule.

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to to understand the math steps to go from Eqn. (1) to Eqn. (2).

$$\tag{1} q(x,t)=\frac{-V_t(1+\delta f(c,g))}{P(x,t)}\cdot \left(\frac{dP_o}{dt}\right)$$

$$\tag{2} \frac{-V_t P'_o(t)(1+\delta G(c))}{P_o(t)}=i+mP_o(t)$$

In Eqn. (1):

- $\delta=2 \phi LA/(3V_t)$
- $f(c,g)=(c+1)(1-2c)+(2c-g)\cdot \sqrt{(c+1)(c+g)}$
- $c=\frac{a^2}{4P_o(P_o+a)}$
- $a\equiv i/m=2(P_a+b)$; where $P_a$ and $b$ are constants & not dependent on distance
- $g\equiv (1-x/L)$

$q$ is volumetric flow rate as a function of length and time, $V_t$ is volume of a tank, $P$ is pressure as a function of length and time, $\phi$ is porosity, $L$ is length, $A$ is area, and $x$ is distance from 0 to $L$.

I believe my issue is in understanding how the chain rule works.

To begin, substitute Eqn. (1) into Darcy's relation: $q_x=\frac{-k_x A}{\mu}\frac{dP}{dx}$

$$\tag{3} \frac{-V_t(1+\delta f(c,g))}{P(x,t)}P'_o=\frac{-k_x A}{\mu}\frac{dP}{dx}$$

Using Klinkenberg's relation for gas permeability: $k(x,t)=k_l (1+b/P(x,t))$ in Eqn. (3) we have:

$$\tag{4} \frac{-V_t(1+\delta f(c,g))}{P(x,t)}P'_o=\frac{-k_l A (1+b/P(x,t))}{\mu}\frac{dP}{dx}$$

Seperate variables and integrate pressure with respect to the length of the core (these are equations that describe gas flow through a cylindrical rock core of length $L$ and cross-sectional area $A$, FYI):

$$\tag{5} \frac{V_t \mu P'_o}{k_l A} \int_0^L 1 \ dx + \frac{V_t \mu P'_o \delta}{k_l A} \int_0^L f(c,g) \ dg = ....[\text{pressure terms here}] $$

My problem is understanding the integration of the $f(c,g)$ term.  $c$ is not a function of length.  $g$ is equal to $1-x/L$, therefore it is a function of length, $x$.

So I know the chain rule is: $\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{df}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dg}$

Since

$$g=1-\frac{x}{L} \rightarrow gL=1-x \rightarrow x=gL-1$$

therefore

$$\frac{dx}{dg}=\frac{d(gL)}{dg}-\require{cancel} \cancelto{0}{\frac{d(1)}{dg}}=L$$

therefore

$$\frac{df}{dg}=L\frac{df}{dx}$$

I'm not sure how or why but somehow, I think, the chain rule allows me to integrate $f(c,g)$ with respect to g?

\begin{align}
\tag{a} \frac{V_t \mu P'_o}{k_l A} \int_0^L 1 \ dx + \frac{V_t \mu P'_o \delta}{k_l A} \int_0^L f(c,g) \ dg &= \\\\ \tag{b} \frac{V_t \mu P'_o L}{k_l A}+\frac{V_t \mu P'_o L \delta G(c)}{k_l A} &= \\\\ \tag{c} \frac{V_t \mu P'_o}{k_l A}(L+L\delta G(c)) &= \\\\ \tag{d} \frac{V_t \mu P'_o L (1+\delta G(c))}{k_l A} &= \\\\ ...\text{algebra}.... \\\\ \tag{2} \frac{-V_t P'_o(t)(1+\delta G(c))}{P_o(t)}&=i+mP_o(t)
\end{align}

So from Eqn. (a) to Eqn. (b), I can put the $L$ in the numerator of the second term because $\frac{df}{dg}=L\frac{df}{dx}$?

**Edit:**

Evaluation of the integral for $f(c,g)$, to show where the G(c) came from:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1}f_{[c,g]}\,dg\,=G_{[c]}\,=\int_{0}^{1}[(c+1)(1-2c)+(2c-g)\cdot \sqrt{(c+1)(c+g)}]\ dg \
\end{equation}

factor out constants and integrate the sum term by term:
\begin{align}
&=(-2c-c+1) \cdot \int_{0}^{1} 1\ dg + \int_{0}^{1} (2c-g) \cdot \sqrt{(c+1)(c+g)}\ dg \\
\nonumber\\
&=[(-2c-c+1) \cdot g] \biggr |_{0}^{1} + \int_{0}^{1} (2c-g) \cdot \sqrt{(c+1)(c+g)}\ dg
\end{align}
\

for the integrand $(2c-g) \cdot \sqrt{(c+1)(c+g)}$, substitute $u=\sqrt{c+g}$ and $du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c+g}}\, dg$
\begin{align}
&= \int_{0}^{1} (2c-g) \cdot \sqrt{(c+1)} \sqrt{(c+g)}\ dg \\
&= \int (2c-g) \cdot \sqrt{(c+1)} \cdot u\ dg \\
&= \int (2c-g) \cdot \sqrt{(c+1)} \cdot u \cdot 2\sqrt{c+g} \ du \\
&= \int (2c-g) \cdot \sqrt{(c+1)} \cdot u \cdot 2 \cdot u \ du \\
&= \int (2c-g) \cdot \sqrt{(c+1)} \cdot 2u^2 \ du \\
&= 2 \int (2c-g) \cdot \sqrt{(c+1)} \cdot u^2 \ du \\
&= 2\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot \int (2c-g) \cdot u^2 \ du \\
&= 2\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot \int (3c-u^2) \cdot u^2 \ du \\
&= 2\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot \int u^2(3c-u^2) \ du \\
&= 2\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot \int (3cu^2-u^4) \ du \\
&= 2\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot \int 3cu^2 \ du - 2\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot \int u^4 \ du \\
&= 6c\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot \int u^2 \ du - 2\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot \int u^4 \ du \\
&= \frac{6}{3}c\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot u^3 - \frac{2}{5}\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot u^5 \\
&= [2c\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot (c+g)^{3/2} - \frac{2}{5}\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot (c+g)^{5/2}]\biggr |_{0}^{1} \\
\end{align}

therefore, we have:
\begin{equation}
=[(-2c-c+1) \cdot g] \biggr |_{0}^{1} + [2c\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot (c+g)^{3/2} - \frac{2}{5}\, \sqrt{(c+1)}\cdot (c+g)^{5/2}]\biggr |_{0}^{1} 
\end{equation}

\begin{multline}
=(-2c-c+1)(1)+2c\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot (c+1)^{3/2} - \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot (c+1)^{5/2}\\ - 2c\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot c^{3/2} + \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot c^{5/2}
\end{multline}
\

looking at the first three terms on the left, we simplify:
\begin{multline*}
\underbrace{(-2c-c+1)(1)+2c\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot (c+1)^{3/2} - \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot (c+1)^{5/2}}\\ - 2c\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot c^{3/2} + \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot c^{5/2}
\end{multline*}

\begin{align}
&=(-2c-c+1)+2c\, (c+1)^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{2}} \\
&=(-2c-c+1)+2c\, (c+1)^{\frac{4}{2}} - \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{\frac{6}{2}} \\
&=(-2c-c+1)+2c\, (c+1)^{2} - \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{3} \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+2c\, (c+1)(c+1)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{3} \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+2c\, (c(c+1)+c+1)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{3} \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+2\, (cc(c+1)+cc+c)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{3} \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+2\, (ccc+cc+cc+c)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{3} \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+2\, (c^3+c^2+c^2+c)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{3} \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+2\, (c^3+2c^2+c)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{3} \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+ (2c^3+4c^2+2c)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{3} \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+ (2c^3+4c^2+2c)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)(c+1)^{2} \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+ (2c^3+4c^2+2c)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c(c+1)^{2}+(c+1)^{2}) \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+ (2c^3+4c^2+2c)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c(c+1)(c+1)+(c+1)^{2}) \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+ (2c^3+4c^2+2c)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c(c(c+1)+c+1)+(c+1)^{2}) \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+ (2c^3+4c^2+2c)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c^2(c+1)+c^2+c)+(c+1)^{2}) \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+ (2c^3+4c^2+2c)- \frac{2}{5}\, (c^3+2c^2+c)+(c+1)^{2}) \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+ (2c^3+4c^2+2c)- \frac{2}{5}\, c^3+\frac{4}{5}\, c^2+\frac{2}{5}\, c-\frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{2}) \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+ (2c^3+4c^2+2c)- \frac{2}{5}\, c^3+\frac{4}{5}\, c^2+\frac{2}{5}\, c-\frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)(c+1) \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+ (2c^3+4c^2+2c)- \frac{2}{5}\, c^3+\frac{4}{5}\, c^2+\frac{2}{5}\, c-\frac{2}{5}\, (c^2+2c+1) \\
&=-2c^2-c+1+ (2c^3+4c^2+2c)- \frac{2}{5}\, c^3+\frac{4}{5}\, c^2+\frac{2}{5}\, c-\frac{2}{5}\, c^2 -\frac{4}{5}\, c -\frac{2}{5}
\end{align}

group terms:
\begin{equation}
=2c^3-\frac{2}{5}\, c^3+4c^2-2c^2-\frac{4}{5}\, c^2-\frac{2}{5}\, c^2+2c-c-\frac{2}{5}\, c-\frac{4}{5}\, c+1-\frac{2}{5}
\end{equation}

multiply by common denominator, $\frac{5}{5}$:
\begin{equation}
=\frac{10}{5}\, c^3-\frac{2}{5}\, c^3+\frac{20}{5}\, c^2-\frac{10}{5}\, c^2-\frac{4}{5}\, c^2-\frac{2}{5}\, c^2+\frac{10}{5}\, c- \frac{5}{5}\, c-\frac{2}{5}\, c-\frac{4}{5}\, c+\frac{5}{5}-\frac{2}{5}
\end{equation}

simplify:
\begin{equation}
=\frac{8}{5}\, c^3+\frac{4}{5}\, c^2-\frac{1}{5}\, c+\frac{3}{5}
\end{equation}

factor:
\begin{align}
&=\frac{1}{5}(8c^3+4c^2-c+3)\\
&=\frac{1}{5}(c(8c^2+4c-1)+3)\\
&=\frac{1}{5}(c(c(8c+4)-1)+3)\\
&=\frac{1}{5}(c+1)(8c^2-4c+3)
\end{align}

looking at the last two terms on the right, we simplify:
\begin{multline*}
(-2c-c+1)(1)+2c\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot (c+1)^{3/2} - \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot (c+1)^{5/2}\\ \underbrace{- 2c\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot c^{3/2} + \frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2}\cdot c^{5/2}}
\end{multline*}

we have to multiply by the same common denominator as before, $\frac{5}{5}$:
\begin{align}
&=-\frac{10}{5}\, c(c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{3/2}+\frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{5/2}\\
&=-\frac{10}{5}\, c(c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{3/2}+\frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{\frac{3}{2}+\frac{2}{2}} \\
&=-\frac{10}{5}\, c(c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{3/2}+\frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{3/2} \cdot c^{2/2} \\
&=-\frac{10}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{3/2} \cdot c+\frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{3/2} \cdot c^{2/2} \\
&=-\frac{10}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{3/2} \cdot c^{2/2}+\frac{2}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{3/2} \cdot c^{2/2} \\
&=-\frac{8}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{3/2} \cdot c^{2/2} \\
&=-\frac{8}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{\frac{3}{2}+ \frac{2}{2}} \\
&=-\frac{8}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{5/2} 
\end{align}

therefore:
\begin{equation}
G_{[c]}\,=\int_{0}^{1}[(c+1)(1-2c)+(2c-g)\cdot \sqrt{(c+1)(c+g)}]\ dg = \frac{1}{5}(c+1)(8c^2-4c+3)-\frac{8}{5}\, (c+1)^{1/2} \cdot c^{5/2} 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my answer:

\begin{equation}
q(x,t)=\frac{-V_t(1+\delta f[c,g(x)])}{P(x,t)}\left(\frac{dP_o}{dt}\right)
\end{equation}

substitute into Darcy's relation: $q_x=\frac{-k_x A}{\mu}\frac{dP}{dx}$

\begin{equation}
\frac{-V_t(1+\delta f[c,g(x)])}{P(x,t)}P'_o=\frac{-k_x A}{\mu}\frac{dP}{dx}
\end{equation}

Using Klinkenberg's relation for gas permeability: $k(x,t)=k_l(1+b/(P(x,t)+P_a))$

\begin{equation}
\frac{-V_t(1+\delta f[c,g(x)])}{P(x,t)}P'_o=\frac{-k_l A (1+b/(P(x,t)+P_a))}{\mu}\frac{\partial P(x,t)}{\partial x}
\end{equation}

*The $P(x,t)$ term on the left-hand side of the equation is absolute pressure, equal to gauge pressure plus atmospheric pressure.

Seperate variables and integrate pressure with respect to the length of the core

\begin{align}
\frac{V_t \mu P'_o}{k_l A}(1+\delta f[c,g(x)])\ dx &= (P(x,t)+P_a)\left(1+\frac{b}{(P(x,t)+P_a)}\right)\ dP(x,t) \\
\nonumber\\
&= \left(P(x,t)+P_a+\frac{(P(x,t)+P_a)b}{(P(x,t)+P_a)}\right) \ dP(x,t) \\
\nonumber\\
&=(P(x,t)+P_a+b) \ dP(x,t) \\
\nonumber\\
\frac{V_t \mu P'_o}{k_l A} \int_0^L 1 \ dx + \frac{V_t \mu P'_o \delta}{k_l A} \int_0^L f[c,g(x)] \ dx &=
\end{align}

we need to swap the bounds of integration for the $f[c,g(x)]$ term if we are to integrate with respect to $g$ and $g$ is a function of $x$.

since:
\begin{align}
g&=1-\frac{x}{L}\\
gL&=L-x\\
x&=L-gL
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
x=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $g=1$;}\\
L & \text{if $g=0$.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dg}&=\frac{dL}{dg}-\frac{d(gL)}{dg}\\
\nonumber\\
\frac{dx}{dg}&=-L\\
\nonumber\\
dx&=-L \ dg
\end{align}

therefore:

\begin{equation}
\frac{V_t \mu P'_o}{k_l A} \int_0^L 1 \ dx - \frac{V_t \mu P'_o L \delta}{k_l A} \int_1^0 f[c,g(x)] \ dg =
\end{equation}

to flip the bounds of integration we can multiply the term by $-1$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{V_t \mu P'_o}{k_l A} \int_0^L 1 \ dx + \frac{V_t \mu P'_o L \delta}{k_l A} \int_0^1 f[c,g(x)] \ dg =
\end{equation}

finishing our integration:

\begin{align}
\frac{V_t \mu P'_o}{k_l A} \int_0^L 1 \ dx + \frac{V_t \mu P'_o L \delta}{k_l A} \int_0^1 f[c,g(x)] \ dg &= \int_{P_o}^{P_l} P(x,t) \ dP_x+\int_{P_o}^{P_l} P_a \ dP_x+\int_{P_o}^{P_l} b \ dP_x \\
\nonumber\\
\frac{V_t \mu P'_o L}{k_l A}+\frac{V_t \mu P'_o L \delta G(c)}{k_l A} &= \frac{P_l^2}{2}-\frac{P_o^2}{2}+P_l P_a-P_o P_a+P_l b-P_o b\\
\nonumber\\
\frac{V_t \mu P'_o}{k_l A}(L+L\delta G(c)) &=\frac{1}{2}(P_l-P_o)(P_l+P_o+2P_a+2b)\\
\nonumber\\
\frac{-2 V_t \mu P'_o L (1+\delta G(c))}{k_l A (P_o-P_l)} &= P_l+P_o+2P_a+2b
\end{align}

If we now switch to gauge pressure (psig), and express permeability in millidarcies, the equation becomes (since $P_l=0$ psig and $k \text{[mD]}=\frac{k\text{[D]}}{1000}$):

\begin{align} 
\frac{-2 V_t \mu P'_o(t) L (1+\delta G(c))}{\left(\frac{k_l}{1000}\right)A(P_0(t)-0)} &=(0+P_0(t)+2P_a+2b) \\
\nonumber\\ 
\frac{-2000 V_t \mu P'_o(t) L (1+\delta G(c))}{k_lA(P_0(t))} &=P_0(t)+2P_a+2b\\
\nonumber\\
\frac{-V_t P'_o(t) (1+\delta G(c))}{P_0(t)} &=\frac{k_lA}{2000 \times 14.696 \mu L}(P_0(t)+2P_a+2b)
\end{align}

$$ \text{set} \ m=\frac{k_lA}{29,390 \mu L} \text{and} \ i=2(P_a+b)m$$

This equation is the equation of a straight line with intercept $i$ and slope $m$:

\begin{equation} y_c \equiv \frac{-V_t P'_o(t) (1+\delta G(c))}{P_0(t)}=i+mP_0(t)\end{equation}